# Magento : Send/Mail custom form data in PDF file

Tags: magento-1.9, email, custom, forms, pdf

I have create one module for custom form fill by the user while click on submit button the form send two person one for user and second for website owner. This is working fine but i want to send this details of form as a pdf while click on submit button.

> Convert the email output content into PDF

So, how that is possible. please let me know if you have any suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: you need to create pdf with infromation and send that pdf.

Comment: Yes you are correct but how i can do that.?